# Excel: Find value across multiple columns and return header column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find a way to look for "Unknown" value across multiple columns. When it is present, I would like to return all of the header columns that the value appears in into one cell for each row in column B.

For example for row 2 (the first row below my header row), I want it to return every column name that "Unknown" appears from Column F to Column Y for row 2 only and put the column name in B2. I want to repeat that process for all of my 9064 rows.

I am using Excel 2010. I looked up Match Index but was not able to find a way to do what I wanted to do. Is there a way to look for a value across multiple columns and return every column header that values appears in for that row and put all of the column headers into one cell?

[Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEMun.png)

Comment: _" I want the number of times "Unknown" appears"_ and _" return every column header that values appears in for that row and put all of the column headers into one cell"_ seems to contradict... Can you give an explicit example of the result?

Comment: I've made a correction, that was worded poorly. I would like to return every column name that Unknown is present in for each row. So in my image "Data View", for example, I would like it to have B2 say Install_Method_CD Manuf_Cd  Coating_Cd Wall_Thickness Join_Method_Cd etc. because Unknown is in those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a custom function.  First place the following code in a regular module (Alt+F11 >> Insert >> Module >> Copy/paste >> Alt+Q)...

```
Function AConcat(a As Variant, Optional Sep As String = "") As String
' Harlan Grove, Mar 2002

    Dim Y As Variant

    If TypeOf a Is Range Then
        For Each Y In a.Cells
            AConcat = AConcat & Y.Value & Sep
        Next Y
    ElseIf IsArray(a) Then
        For Each Y In a
            AConcat = AConcat & Y & Sep
        Next Y
    Else
        AConcat = AConcat & a & Sep
    End If

    AConcat = Left(AConcat, Len(AConcat) - Len(Sep))

End Function
```

Then enter the following formula in AA2, confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copy down:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(AConcat(IF(LEFT(F2:Y2,3)="Unk",", "&$F$1:$Y$1,"")),", ","",1)
```

Comment: That worked awesome. I'm just noticing that there are some values only as "Unk" and I apologize for not seeing that earlier. Is there an easy correction to do so it would pick up anything with "Unk". There are a couple of fields that were filled in by the user so there could be misspellings and what not so it wouldn't just be "Unk" or "Unknown". I tried adding a wildcard in the Array but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, I've edited the formula so that it now searches for cells that start with "Unk".

Comment: Works PERFECT! Thank you so much!